# What is the dimension of set of all solutions to $y''+ay'+by=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+ay'+by=0,\quad y(0)=y(1)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

Let $V$ be the set of all the solutions of this equation. Then the dimension of $V$?

The answer to it that I think is $1$ but still want to know the exact logic behind this. Help from someone would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** You know the general solution to 
$$y''+ay'+by=0$$
You can write it as 
$$y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$$

When you write 
$$y(0)=y(1)$$ you get
$$C_1 (y_1(1)-y_1(0))+C_2( y_2(1)-y_2(0))=0$$

Now, if 
$$y_1(1)-y_1(0) \neq 0 \mbox{ or } y_2(1)-y_2(0) \neq 0$$
you get a relation between $C_1$ and $C_2$ which means that the general solution can be expressed in terms of only one parameter. Thus the dimension is $1$.

But if

$$y_1(1)-y_1(0) = 0 \mbox{ and } y_2(1)-y_2(0) = 0$$

Something else happens.

Note that when you solve the original equation, the solution has one of three potential forms. The last thing can happen in only one of the situations....