# when two solutions do not form a basis for the solution space to a 2nd order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1,y_2$ be two solutions to the ode $y''(t)+p(t)y'(t)+q(t)=0$ on the interval $a<t<b$ where both $p,q$ are continuous function.

I want to show that the solutions $y_1,y_2$ do not form a basis for the solution space to the differential equation when just one of the two following conditions are satisfied:

there exist $c \in (a,b)$ such that $y_1(c)=y_2(c)=0$

$y_1$ and $y_2$ archieve a maximum or minimum at the same point in the interval $a<t<b$.

To show this I just have to show that in either case $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly depending. however I find this quite hard to do since I have so little to work with.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646410/what-is-the-dimension-of-set-of-all-solutions-to-yayby-0

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, because due to the $q(t)$ term the equation is not homogeneous, and so the solution space is not a linear space, meaning it does not have a basis.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a solution to $y'' + p y' + q = 0,$ then so is every translation on $y$.

So given $y_1, y_2$ consider the solution $y_3 = y_2 + 1.$ If the space of solutions would have been generated by $y_1, y_2,$ you would have $y_3= a y_1 + by_2.$

This is impossible since $a y_1(c) + by_2(c) = 0 \neq 1 = y_3(c)$

Comment: Why should $y_2+1$ be a solution?

Comment: Because $(y_2 + 1)' = y_2' , (y_2 + 1)'' = y_2'',$ and your differential equation depends only on first and second derivative of the function: not on the function itself.

Comment: Ah, good point, my eyes saw "$q$" and my mind read "$qy$".

Comment: That's what happens when you are used to the difficult cases :)

Comment: However, this means the equation is not homogeneous, and so the whole question is nonsensical.